# Strange access to my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I put my first application (Rails) in a GoDaddy server and after a month I realize some strange access to it.

They are:

```
Started GET "/IPC$" for 103.246.38.196 at 2015-10-23 05:57:33 -0200
Started GET "/sitemap.xml" for 198.20.69.74 at 2015-10-23 03:02:50 -0200
Started GET "/admin/config.php" for 186.103.216.82 at 2015-10-23 08:58:08 -0200
```

This is normal ? How is trying to access these pages?

Comment: GoDaddy customers have been the targets of many hacks recently - I think one factor is that GD hosts many out of date and insecure PHP applications which makes it a juicy target. I would definitely check up on it and then get off shared hosting. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2892632/driveby-attack-relies-on-hacked-godaddy-accounts.html

Comment: `/sitemap.xml` is pretty legit - spiders like google check that. "/IPC$" is used for Remote Procedure Calls - this a warning flag. And "/admin/config.php" seems like someone is fishing for a unsecured PHP backend. As long as your hosting does not actually provide any of the two no harm is done. Its just fishing.

Comment: @max, actually I´m using a VPS on Godaddy. When you said to get off shared hosting, is this included? Do you have another good option?

Comment: A VPS is usually better than shared hosting provided you know how to secure it and keep things up to date. Shared hosting often uses outdated versions of PHP, MySql etc to support customers who don't update. SAAS platforms like Heroku are ages ahead of this.